# What is the correct way to document EventEmitters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, jsdoc

I am trying to document an EventEmitter, but the documentation isn't very clear about what should be done, and every information I could find when searching for help or examples is even more confusing.

My final goal is to have a class that has a `on` method, that can listen to multiple events, all of which having a different callback.
For example, if I have a `messageEvent` event, that takes a single `String` as parameter in its callback, I would like my IDE (in my case VSCode) to tell me, when I listen to a `messageEvent`, that the callback for it takes a `String`, and not an unknown number of any type.

I know this is possible with JSDoc, as I already worked with npm packages that documents them well (e.g. [discord.js](https://discord.js.org)), but every time I try something different from what I already tried, I get even more confused.

What I already know is that I have to use `@event`, `@fires` and `@listens` tags, but I understand neither how nor where.

Could someone explains to me what I am supposed to do, possibly with examples? I would be very grateful.